# To retrieve xml node values from multidimensional array

Tags: php, xml, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am storing an xml response in array format. Now i need to get the node attribute values like HotelLocation, hotelCode etc from the array. Below is the format how my array looks like :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
        (
            [media] => <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP:Body><hotel:HotelMediaLinksRsp TraceId="trace" TransactionId="69B008C27F00000109CA96A4918F80C6" ResponseTime="77" xmlns:common_v25_0="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v25_0" xmlns:hotel="http://www.travelport.com/schema/hotel_v25_0"><hotel:HotelPropertyWithMediaItems><hotel:HotelProperty HotelChain="CP" HotelCode="36588" HotelLocation="DXB" Name="CROWNE PLAZA FESTIVAL CITY" VendorLocationKey="1tTgCxLKRUuwf3+sFMCwFg==" HotelTransportation="Limo" ReserveRequirement="Other" ParticipationLevel="Enhanced Best Available Rate participant" Availability="Available" FeaturedProperty="true" NetTransCommissionInd="C"><hotel:PropertyAddress><hotel:Address>DUBAI-FESTIVAL CITY</hotel:Address></hotel:PropertyAddress></hotel:HotelProperty></hotel:HotelPropertyWithMediaItems></hotel:HotelMediaLinksRsp></SOAP:Body></SOAP:Envelope>
)
)
```

(Php)

Comment: This is SOAP, have you tried to use the SOAP extension?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to access that part of your array.

If it is stored as `$MyResponse` you would access `[0]` using `$MyResponse[0]`.

I would then turn the XML into an array to make it easier to access like so. See more on SimpleXML [here.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php)

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($MyResponse[0]);
```

Then you can access the individual elements like an array.
For Example..

```
echo $xml->a->b->b['name'];
```